# How to write a R function that uses other R functions as arguments?

Tags: r, function, arguments

This is a function I have to write. It takes a function as an argument and data.

`evaluate <- function(func, dat){}`, and the output should be something like the following:

1. `evaluate(sum, c(2, 4, 6))` should evaluate to 12
2. `evaluate(median, c(7, 40, 9))` should evaluate to 9
3. `evaluate(floor, 11.1)` should evaluate to 11

I am getting confused about how to write this function.

Any hints helps! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```r
evaluate <- function(FUN, dat){
  return(FUN(dat))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call`:

```
evaluate <- function(fun, args){
  do.call(fun, args)}
```

But `args` has to be a list:

```
evaluate(sum, list(c(2, 4, 6)))
```